# Multiple foreach for multiple list data

Tags: c#, foreach

I have 2 string list.

```
var justiceCourtName = formCollection["JusticeCourtName"];
var courtId = formCollection["CourtID"];
var justiceCourtNameList = justiceCourtName.Split(',');
var courtIdList = courtId.ToList();
```

**justiceCourtNameList  values below:**

```
"New York"

"Paris"
```

**courtIdList values below:**

```
"10.33"

"43.15"
```

**My question:**

I need to use foreach for justiceCourtNameList  and courtIdList after that , from justiceCourtNameList   to Name (below) and from courtIdList to lawCourtId one by one.

But I do not know how can i set justiceCourtNameList   and courtIdList  one by one to new LawCourt ?

```
var lawCourt = new LawCourt { JusticeCourtID = lawCourtId, Name = lawCourtName };


ServiceLibraryHelper.LawServiceHelper.UpdateLawCourt(lawCourt); // Update
```

Comment: editing is ok please help thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get every combination of `justiceCourtNameList` and `courtIdList` or something else? The question is far from clear.

Comment: how can i use multiple foreach thanks

Comment: if count of nameList and idList are same, you can use for loop...

Comment: "How can I...": there are multiple options to "use multiple `foreach` loop", which makes sense depends what you are trying to do. But that isn't clear (of course sometimes someone will guess correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, what you want is the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698.aspx) extension method:

```
var results = courtIdList
                  .Zip(justiceCourtNameList,
                       (lawCourtId, lawCourtName) =>
                           new LawCourt
                           {
                               JusticeCourtID = lawCourtId,
                               Name = lawCourtName
                           )};
```

It enumerates the lists in parallel, and associates the current item from the first list with the current item from the second. The lambda expression specifies what to return in the output sequence, based on the pair of items from the input sequences.

Answer (score 1):

It might be `Enumerable.Zip` can serve your purpose ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);

foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

// This code produces the following output:

// 1 one
// 2 two
// 3 three
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `foreach` operator but the `for` operator. Check before that both arrays have equal length.

```
List<string> justiceCourtNameList = ...
List<double> courtIdList = ...

if(justiceCourtNameList.Count != courtIdList.Count) {
    throw new ArgumentException("justiceCourtNameList and courtIdList must have the same length");
}

for(int i=0; i<justiceCourtNameList.Count; i++) {

    string justiceCourtName = justiceCourtNameList[i];
    double courtId = courtIdList[i];

    // DO HERE WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
}
```

Double synchronous iteration with `foreach` is not possible.